Smooth function on bounded domain is Lipschitz
I am unsure, if my proof is correct. Would anybody please verify it?
Let $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be smooth, and let $U\subset R^d$ be a bounded domain, i.e., $U$ is open, connected and bounded.
Hence the closure $cl(U)$ is closed, bounded and connected. As the restriction
$f|_{cl(U)}$ is smooth on $cl(U)$, it is Lipschitz.
Moreover $U\subset \overline U$, $f|_{U}$ is Lipschitz as well.

What you have written is correct. You have deduced that smooth functions are Lipschitz on a bounded open domain from the fact that they are Lipschitz on a bounded closed domain. The latter point is actually the harder part of the proof.

Also it may be worth thinking about why the closure of a bounded set is bounded.

@Mentastin Thank you very much! Regarding boundedness. Isn't it obvious? The closure of $U$ is the intersection of all closed sets that contain $U$, and thus contained in each closed set (or ball) that contains $U$.

Obviousness is in the eye of the beholder :) But yes, that is a good argument.
